# Read UTF8 chars in req.path using Express.JS in Node

Tags: node.js, express, path, request

Express reads this request path - `/wiąz.txt` as `/wiÄz.txt`, and I get `/wiÄz.txt doesn't exist`, but `wiąz.txt` exists. Is it possible to read utf8 chars in request path?

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
app.set('etag', false);
app.set('x-powered-by', false);

app.route('*').all(function(req, res) {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

    try {
        var file = fs.readFileSync('.' + req.path, 'utf8'); // req.path starts always with /, the result is ./FILE
        res.send(file);
    } catch (e) {
        res.send(req.path + " doesn't exist");
    }
});

app.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('HTTP Server is now running on port 80');
});
```

Comment: Can you post your code in question?

Comment: Done. See it again.

Comment: check this `fs.readFileSync('.' + decodeURIComponent(req.path)+'.txt', 'utf8')`

Comment: @LalitGoswami Still `/wi%C4%85z.txt doesn't exist` :|

Comment: I think you have used `encodeURIComponent`, ensure you have used `decodeURIComponent`.

Comment: @LalitGoswami You're right. Can you post your answer below? So I can accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var file = fs.readFileSync('.' + decodeURIComponent(req.path), 'utf8');
res.send(file);
```